# Erro ao subir site em WORDPRESS

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

Desenvolvi um site em WORDPRESS e no meu servidor local está funcionando corretamente. Ao subí-lo, fiz todas as configurações necessários (mudar URL base no bd, configurar wp-admin), só especificamente uma página não está carregando por completo. Em determinada parte do código a aplicação para de rodar. Especificamente nesta página estou usando o plugin MetaBox. Alguém teve algum problema assim?

Comment: Nos logs é apresentado algum erro?

Comment: Tente imprimir o erro que está acontecendo, ativando o modo debug. Adicione o código abaixo no seu wp-config.php: `define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );` Colar o código antes da linha que contém: `/* That's all, stop editing! Happy blogging. */` Cole aqui a mensagem de erro para podermos te ajudar.

Comment: Obrigado @LeonelCostaBraz. Ao ativar o DEBUG consegui encontrar o erro.